# Closing Swing modal popups

Tags: java, swing, popup, modal-dialog

When I am trying to hide or close popup dialog invoked as a modal, the components disappears as they should, but the grey screen that indicates modality of the window is still visible, until the fist mouse click event at this window area.

```
WebPopup darkenScreen = new WebPopup(PopupStyle.gray);
ContructPopUP(darkenScreen);
darkenScreen.showPopupAsModal(this);
```

And popup settings method :

```
private void ContructPopUP(WebPopup darkenScreen)
{
    final JFrame mFrame = this;
    final WebTextField inputTime = new WebTextField("(sekundy)");
    darkenScreen.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    darkenScreen.add(new WebLabel("Podaj czas : "));
    darkenScreen.add(inputTime);
    darkenScreen.add(new WebButton(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int secTime = Integer.parseInt(inputTime.getText());
            if (secTime > 0 && secTime < 7200)
            {
                Connection.TurnOff(secTime);
                System.out.println("clicked!");
            }

            darkenScreen.hidePopup();
        }
    }));
}
```

When invoking as ordinary popup everything disappears as indented. I've tried to close it in many ways but none of them worked.

Before clicking button and executing popup.hide :
[image: Before popup.hide()]

after doing it :

[image: after]

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [WebLaF library](http://weblookandfeel.com/), I think your problem might be caused by the [`PopupLayer.hidePopup`](https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf/blob/5285505dcdcfcb57d03a5cb77c411a10facae511/modules/ui/src/com/alee/managers/popup/PopupLayer.java#L116-L137) method. This method is called by the `WebPopup.hidePopup` method and should hide the modal popup, but as you noticed, the gray layer does not disappear. If you look at [`PopupLayer.hideAllPopups`](https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf/blob/5285505dcdcfcb57d03a5cb77c411a10facae511/modules/ui/src/com/alee/managers/popup/PopupLayer.java#L84-L92), all popups are removed in this method and **the popup layer is made invisible**. I do not have experience with the WebLaF library and it feels hackish, but you might be able to solve your problem by hiding the popup layer yourself:

```
import com.alee.laf.button.WebButton;
import com.alee.laf.label.WebLabel;
import com.alee.laf.text.WebTextField;
import com.alee.managers.popup.PopupStyle;
import com.alee.managers.popup.WebPopup;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ModalWebPopup {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new ModalWebPopup().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow: modal WebPopup");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button1 = new JButton("Show a modal WebPopup");
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        button1.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            final WebPopup darkenScreen = new WebPopup(PopupStyle.gray);
            constructPopup(darkenScreen);
            darkenScreen.showPopupAsModal(frame);
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void constructPopup(final WebPopup darkenScreen) {
        //final JFrame mFrame = this;
        final WebTextField inputTime = new WebTextField("(sekundy)");
        darkenScreen.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        darkenScreen.add(new WebLabel("Podaj czas : "));
        darkenScreen.add(inputTime);
        darkenScreen.add(new WebButton(actionEvent -> {
            int secTime = Integer.parseInt(inputTime.getText());
            if (secTime > 0 && secTime < 7200) {
                //Connection.TurnOff(secTime);
                System.out.println("clicked!");
            }

            System.out.print("Hide the modal WebPopup ");

            // Normal way to hide the popup:
            //darkenScreen.hidePopup();

            System.out.println("by making the parent of the WebPopup invisible.");

            // Alternative way to hide the popup:
            darkenScreen.getParent().setVisible(false);

            // Compare the PopupLayer.hideAllPopups and PopupLayer.hidePopup methods
            // for more details.
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, WebPopup.getParent().setVisible(false) made the job done, both Popup and gray layer are being hidden now.